# By the look/looks of things

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+look+of+things

Example from idioms dictionary:

"The detective said that, by the look**s** of thing**s**, she is probably hiding out somewhere."

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by-the-look-s-of-things

Example from Cambridge dictionary:

"By the look of thing**s**, we won't finish till next week."

As far as I am concerned 'looks of things' is grammatically wrong but colloquially correct. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It's silly to say that something is "grammatically wrong but colloquially correct". Grammar **is** colloquial use, or rather its record and structure. Either singular or plural will do with that idiom, especially when dealing with a large visual area, usually in disorder. So, as often happens in English, it's speaker's choice; what you hear is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The only people who worry about grammar are grammatical pedants.  Your example is 100% fine in English.  What 'rules' some people chose to impose are irrelevant.  If we followed that route you's be saying to people "You can't say that!  It's ungrammatical."   Once in a while people don't make sense, but mostly that's because they've got their brain-cells in a twist and worms turn to water.

Comment: '"you's" should be "youse'd"